# How to check UserId exists or not in sharepoint list using angularjs

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have implemented post method for inserting userid into list.

So how to check whether inserted User Id exists in SharePoint list or not,in angularJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the currently logged in user in sharepoint by following code:

```
var userId = _spPageContextInfo.userId;
```

After that before showing popup, make a REST call on the list to check the current user is already exist in list or not. 
(Assuming your column in list is of people and group type and name is "LoggedUsers").

```
$.ajax({
          url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListName')/items$select=Title,LoggedUsers/Id&$expand=LoggedUsers&$filter=LoggedUsers/Id eq " + userId,
method: "GET",
headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" 
},
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

If you got any results through this call, then hide the popup or if didn't got any results, then show popup to add current user in list.

Ignore the typos and please upvoted if this answer helped you in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Use the /_api/web/ensureUser service. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33259576/sharepoint-2013-ensureuser-via-rest-api) are the ajax instructions. The specific post you make through angular depends on the version you are using.

Broadly, though, something like this for angularJS :

```
//the call to the service, using post headers w/ X-RequestDigest
postDataAsync(url, JSON.stringify({ 'logonName': user }), headers).then(function (response) {

});

//the service
postdataasync(url, data, spHeaders){
   $http.post(url, data, { headers: spHeaders }).then(function (response) {

   }, function(error){}
});

});
```